# Date field validation in Django

Tags: python, django, date

I have a model where users can enter date in (yyyy-mm-dd).
How do I make sure that the date is not in the past days and within next 7 days including today?

```
class Tables(models.Model): 
    tablerequiretime = models.TimeField()
```

**For example,**

- If user enter 2020-6-26, it should raise an error as date is yesterday
- If user enter 2020-6-27, it should accept as date is today.
- If user enter 2020-7-4, it should accept as date is within this week.

Is it possible to implement logic in model layer? Or should I opt for serialize fields?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033758/what-is-the-best-practice-to-validate-a-django-datefield-at-the-model-level-as-p

Comment: @ParthVerma thanks,I will look into this

Answer (score 1):

You must use **DateField** instead of **Timedfield**.